# PiCamera storing an image in an RGBArray

Tags: python, pi

Hi i'm trying to capture a low res image during recording with the PiCamera module. However it crashes on the camera.capture line giving the following error

> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/array.py", line 238,
>   in flush
>       self.array = bytes_to_rgb(self.getvalue(), self.size or self.camera.resolution)   File
>   "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/array.py", line 127, in
>   bytes_to_rgb
>       'Incorrect buffer length for resolution %dx%d' % (width, height)) picamera.exc.PiCameraValueError: Incorrect buffer length for
>   resolution 1280x726

This is my code so far:

```
from picamera import PiCamera
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
import numpy as np
import time

camera = PiCamera()

resolution = (128,80)
camera.resolution = (1280, 726)
camera.start_preview()
time.sleep(2)
RGBArray = PiRGBArray(camera)

camera.capture(RGBArray, format='rgb',splitter_port=0,resize=resolution)
print("i crash on the line above")
```

If i set the camera resolution to camera.resolution = (128,80) and remove the "resize" parameter from camera.capture() it works fine but i want to record in a higher resolution. I can't seem to find the solution anywhere on this.

SOLVED PiRGBArray(camera) needs to be changed to PiRGBArray(camera,size=128,80)

Comment: Please mark your question as _solved_ when you've solved the problem yourself. You may also simply answer your own question and mark that as the accepted answer to help other users with the same problem quickly identify the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PiRGBArray(camera) needs to be changed to PiRGBArray(camera,size=128,80)